# How do I get all text by click on each 'a' element?

Tags: jquery

I am working on MVC 5 project, there If the user click on **Lighting**, then show like **Mep services > Electrical > Lighting** or even if click on **HT&LT** then show like **Mep services > Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT** like that.

I have tried below jQuery code, It is working fine. But the "Mep services" not showing now.

```js
 $(".breadcrumb-list").click(function () {
        
        var bc = '<ul class="breadcrumb">';

        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        
        $(this).closest("ul").find("li").each(function (i, x) {
            if (i < index) {
                bc += '<li><a href="#">' + $(x).text() + '</a></li>';
            }
        })

        bc += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li></ul>';
        $('#idSearch-item').html(bc).show();
    });
```

```html
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle breadcrumb-list" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">MEP SERVICES <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">

        <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header breadcrumb-list" >Electrical<input type="hidden" value="28"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb-list">Lighting</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="29">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb-list">HT &amp; LT</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="30">
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Now its showing without the **Mep services**,

```html
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12" style="" id="idSearch-item">
    <ul class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="#">Electrical</a></li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                Lighting

            </a>
        </li>
        <li>HT &amp; LT</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How can I do this ? please help me...

Comment: Just to clarify, Do you want to place those `sub-menu` (Mep services > Electrical) under Lighting `menu`?

Comment: @eeya : if the user click on HT&LT then I want to show like this "Mep services > Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT" like that. But now showing "Electrical > Lighting > HT&LT".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. Hope it will help. Just find the text of top most anchor tag and decorate it with a li tag.

```js
$(".breadcrumb-list").click(function () {
        
        var bc = '<ul class="breadcrumb">';
        var parentText = $('li.mega-dropdown').find("a:first()").text();
        bc += '<li><a href="#">' + parentText + '</a></li>'
        var index = $(this).parent().index();
        
        $(this).closest("ul").find("li").each(function (i, x) {
            if (i < index) {
                bc += '<li><a href="#">' + $(x).text() + '</a></li>';
            }
        })

        bc += '<li>' + $(this).text() + '</li></ul>';
        $('#idSearch-item').html(bc).show();
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown open">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle breadcrumb-list" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="true">MEP SERVICES <span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu row">

        <li class="col-sm-3">
            <ul>
                <li class="dropdown-header breadcrumb-list" >Electrical<input type="hidden" value="28"></li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb-list">Lighting</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="29">
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#" class="breadcrumb-list">HT &amp; LT</a>
                    <input type="hidden" value="30">
                </li>                   
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: actually there is have so many `<li class="dropdown mega-dropdown"></li>` after running your code now showing all `$('li.mega-dropdown').find("a:first()").text()`. how can I get only "Mep services" ?

Comment: got it... I did written like this: `  var parentText = $(this).parents().parents('li').children("a:first").text();`

Comment: You can try this too. var parentText = $(this).closest('li.mega-dropdown').children("a:first").text();